# Why do the English dubbed Madoka movies have a static movie menu and not an animated one like the English subbed one?

Tags: anime-production, madoka-magica

When the *Puella Magi Madoka Magica* Movies first came out, they were only Japanese with English subtitles, but the DVD/Blu-ray menus were animated. I remembered that they had small clips from the movie and the background music was that of the music that plays when Sayaka turns into a witch at the end of the first movie.

When the English dubbed version of the movies came out I got them too and after watching the first 2 movies I've noticed they have a totally different menu. This time, it's just a static image, and the background music is different.

I am wondering why this is. Would it not have been easier just to use the same menu? Also, is this a common practice when an anime is first released subbed but is then later re-released dubbed that the movie menu is remade (and possibly made less dynamic/flashy in the English dub release)?